# What level of spell slot is "used" when duplicating a spell with Wish?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wish

*Wish* states:

> The basic use of this spell is to duplicate any other
>   spell of 8th level or lower. You don't need to meet any
>   requirements in that spell, including costly Components.
>   The spell simply takes effect.

If I choose to duplicate *Magic Missile* do I create 3 darts (level 1), 10 darts (level 8), or 11 darts (level 9)? Or can I choose how many to create from some range?

In other words, what is the level of the spell slot "used" by the duplicated spell?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Whichever you like, provided it is at most 8th level.

See [this sage advice](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2018/01/16/when-wish-is-used-to-duplicate-a-spell-can-it-be-duplicated-at-a-higher-level/):

> When Wish is used to duplicate a spell, can it be duplicated at a higher level? For example, a 7th level Banishing Smite to bypass Limited Magic Immunity.
>
> -> A spell you duplicate with wish can be cast at a higher level, as long as that level is no higher than 8th.

You still expend a 9th-level slot, of course.

Answer (score 25):

## The slot used to cast *wish* is always 9th

Just to be clear, when casting *wish* you only ever actually use a 9th level slot.

## The effective level of the duplicated spell is up to the wisher (max of 8th level)

When you cast *wish* you get to decide what level the resulting spell is cast at per [Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/930977942305251329):

> A spell you duplicate with wish can be cast at a higher level, as long as that level is no higher than 8th.

8th level is the highest level you can cast the spell at because wish can only duplicate a spell of 8th level or lower.

Comment: Wow I always thought it would be at the default level. Mind. Blown.

Answer (score 4):

## You Decide Upon Cast; No Higher Than 8th Level

The slot **consumed** by casting the spell *Wish* will always be a 9th level slot.

The **effect** of the spell you duplicate can be of any level no higher than 8th level.

See relevant [Sage Advice](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2018/01/16/when-wish-is-used-to-duplicate-a-spell-can-it-be-duplicated-at-a-higher-level/) and [Jeremy Crawford Tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/930977942305251329)

> A spell you duplicate with wish can be cast at a higher level, as long as that level is no higher than 8th.